# Removing some option in select 2 after clicking an option in select 1

Tags: javascript

**Apparently, I am trying to remove index 2 in time_sel when I choose frozen II in mov_sel but it's not working. Any suggestions how to remove index 2? Any help will be appreciated, thank you so much**

These are my codes, it looks basic because I am new to Javascript, I'm sorry about that

> This is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getDropDown(){
        var x = document.getElementById("mov_sel");
        var y = document.getElementById("time_sel");

        if (x == "Frozen II") {
            y.remove(2);
        }
    }
  </script>
```

> and this is the body

```
<div class="reg2">NOW SHOWING</div>
    <select name="mov" class="dropdown" id="mov_sel" onchange="getDropDown()"> 
                <option value="Archer">Archer</option>
                <option value="Freedom">Freedom</option>
                <option value="Avengers">Avengers</option>
                <option value="Frozen II">Frozen II</option>
                <option value="Spider-Man: Far from Home">Spider-Man: Far from Home</option>
                <option value="Buy Busts">Buy Busts</option>
                <option value="EERIE">EERIE</option>
                <option value="Manila Kingpin: Untold Story of Asiong Salonga">Manila Kingpin: Untold Story of Asiong Salonga</option>
            </select>

    <div class="reg3">SELECT TIME</div>
    <select name="time" class="dropdown" id="time_sel">
                <option value="1">------------</option> 
                <option value="9:00 – 10:30">9:00 – 10:30</option>
                <option value="11:00 – 12:30">11:00 – 12:30</option>
                <option value="3:00 – 4:30">3:00 – 4:30</option>
                <option value="5:00 – 6:30">5:00 – 6:30</option>

                <option value="9:00 – 10:30">------------</option> 
                <option value="11:30 – 1:00">11:30 – 1:00</option>
                <option value="2:30 – 4:00">2:30 – 4:00</option>
                <option value="5:00 – 6:30">5:00 – 6:30</option>
                <option value="7:00 – 8:30">7:00 – 8:30</option>

                <option value="9:00 – 10:30">------------</option> 
                <option value="10:30 – 12:30">10:30 – 12:30</option>
                <option value="1:30 – 3:30">1:30 – 3:30</option>
                <option value="4:30 – 6:30">4:30 – 6:30</option>
                <option value="7:00 – 9:00">7:00 – 9:00</option>

                <option value="2">------------</option> 
                <option value="12:00 – 1:45">12:00 – 1:45</option>
                <option value="2:00 – 3:45">2:00 – 3:45</option>
                <option value="4:00 – 5:45">4:00 – 5:45</option>
                <option value="NONE">NONE</option>

                <option value="3">------------</option> 
                <option value="11:00 – 12:30">11:00 – 12:30</option>
                <option value="2:30 – 4:00">2:30 – 4:00</option>
                <option value="4:30 – 6:30">4:30 – 6:30</option>
                <option value="7:00 – 8:30">7:00 – 8:30</option>

                <option value="4">------------</option> 
                <option value="10:45 – 12:00">10:45 – 12:00</option>
                <option value="12:00 – 1:45">12:00 – 1:45</option>
                <option value="2:30 – 4:15">2:30 – 4:15</option>
                <option value="NONE">NONE</option>

                <option value="5">------------</option> 
                <option value="9:00 – 10:30">9:00 – 10:30</option>
                <option value="11:00 – 12:30">11:00 – 12:30</option>
                <option value="2:30 – 4:00">2:30 – 4:00</option>
                <option value="4:30 – 6:30">4:30 – 6:30</option>

                <option value="6">------------</option> 
                <option value="12:00 – 1:45">12:00 – 1:45</option>
                <option value="2:00 – 3:45">2:00 – 3:45</option>
                <option value="4:00 – 5:45">4:00 – 5:45</option>
                <option value="NONE">NONE</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: you just need to change the condition to be `if (x.value == "Frozen II") `, x in your case the the Select element object, and you need to check the value

Answer (score -1):

var x = document.getElementById("mov_sel").value;
var y = document.getElementById("time_sel").value;

You can try this.

Comment: Thank you for answering but it's still not working, I'll try more different methods

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.